# JS - If window height is less than ___px, do something - What is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, html, height

I am trying to send the user to a different url, if their browser height is smaller than a certain value. I want it to be checking for this all the time so have used the setInterval function. I cannot see what is wrong with it...

This is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //if window height is less than 605px, go to google
    setInterval(function changeFont() {
    if (window.innerHeight < 605) {
    window.location = "http://google.com";

    }
    }, 1);
    </script>
```

and before it I run this code which works great:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //if window is wider than 1340px, send to desktop
    setInterval(function sendToDesktop() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 1340) {
    window.location = "../index.html";
    }
    }, 1);

    </script>
```

When I use the code for screen height, the redirect doesn't work, even if the screen height is under 605px. Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: When are you running this code? Before or after other scripts?

Comment: I'd recommend at least 100ms instead

Comment: it is after a different script. see updated question.

Comment: What are the symptoms of "doesn't work"? Does the browser hang on redicrect?

Comment: it just doesn't redirect at all

Comment: Any console errors? Watch the browser tab "loading spinner" - are you sure the browser is not stuck on processing a redirect?

Comment: I tried that @Dien but now the browser just gets stick between the two. The address bar reads google (as if to load the page), then flicks back to the html document in the address bar, whilst the page shows white.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint or console.log in the interval function to see the value of `window.innerHeight`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is time, you have given 1.. Means less than milliseconds...you have given a very small value. 
So what happens is that the script executes so fast that redirection wont happen. 
I tested this, provided 10000 insted of 1, and it worked! So you have to change 1 or use a code shown below(it checks window height everytime)

`<script>
    function setWindowHeight(){
            var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
            if (windowHeight < 605) {
                window.location = "http://google.com";
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("resize",setWindowHeight,false);
</script>`

Comment: Ok thanks. I was initially going to use the browser redirect to go to a different version for smaller devices but wanted to know if I could just change the CSS of some elements. I wanted to see if i could make fonts  smaller but this won't work: document.getElementById("title").style.font-size = "40px";

Comment: try document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize.., dont forget to upvote :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using timer is really a nonsense here. Just define a function which checks if the window is high enough and call it on resize. And don't forget to call it also on the first load.

```
function checkHeightredirectToGoogle() {
  if (window.innerHeight < 605) {
    window.location = "https://google.com";
  }
}  

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  checkHeightredirectToGoogle()
}); 

checkHeightredirectToGoogle(); //first call
```

This solution will be easier to write and maintain and also faster on the client's computer, not mentioning mobile devices, where the improvement is even higher.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is force the browser to queue a function every 1ms. And when the browser finally gets to the queue, it sees a few hundred functions waiting to run. It runs the functions - **ALL** of which ultimately evaluates to

```
window.location = 'http://google.com'
```

So your browser makes a few hundred redirects in a matter of milliseconds. And while it is furiously trying to do so, more functions are getting queued in.

Looking at your code, the problem will be even worse if a user has a screen 1440 x 600. Both redirect conditions will be satisfied.

Please detect and redirect on page load, and then listen for any subsequent `resize` events instead.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', detectAndRedirect);
function detectAndRedirect() {
    if (window.innerHeight < 605) {
        window.location = 'whatever url';
    }
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 1340) {
        window.location = 'whatever url';
    }
}
```

If you really must use timers to detect resolution, the better way to do this would be:

```
var DETECT_PERIOD = 200;  // set something sensible.
setTimeout(detectAndRedirect, DETECT_PERIOD);

function detectAndRedirect() {
    if (window.innerHeight < 605) {
        window.location = 'whatever url';
    }
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 1340) {
        window.location = 'whatever url';
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(detectAndRedirect, DETECT_PERIOD);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't you think that `1` is to small value in this case? These are miliseconds. That's first thing and the second:

> I cannot see what is wrong with it...

So if you cannot see anything wrong then how can we help? What is your exact question? It doesn't redirect? What the console is showing? Any errors?

Comment: I have set an interval of 1 for another script and that runs fine. the problem is that it just isn't redirecting even when the screen height is well under the 605px limit.